# Extend b2ContactListener (C++) with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, box2d, collision-detection

As I'm not a C++ developper, I would like to know if it is possible to extend the b2ContactListener class directly with Objective-C, or if I have to wrap the b2ContactListener.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use box2d with Cocoa requires Objective-C++. . this is a powerful language and a fun way to learn C++.

One of the rules of Objective-C++, is that an Objective-C class cannot extend a C++ class (and vise-versa), thus it is indeed necessary to use composition instead of inheritance (wrap in other words). . . I'm using the term composition here, since ["composition vs inheritance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is a common design strategy to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I use Objective-C++ and I wrapped some of the Box2D functions into Obj-C method. What do you mean by "composition" ?

Comment: By 'composition' I meant wrapping. I was referring to 'composition vs inheritance', which is a (big name for a simple) design strategy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance . . it basically means you class 'contains/is composed of' another class, instead of extending it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap it. There's no way to subclass a C++ class with an Objective-C or Obj-C++ class. So either just create a wrapper in Objective-C++ or create a C++ class to extend it. It should also be noted that files with the extension .mm will be compiled as "Objective-C++" instead of .m to Objective-C.